# Determine if customer is new in customer_save_after

Tags: customer, event-observer, register

I have events that I wish to execute when a customer registers or saves their details.  For this, I am using two events: customer_register_success and customer_save_after.  The problem I am having is that I end up running the task twice as customer_save_after is always called in the same execution as `customer_register_success`.

I have tried to detect whether the customer is new by checking the original data and called `isObjectNew`, but both return data that implies the object is in fact not new.  How can I check to see if the customer is just registering in the customer_save_after event short of setting something in the registry in the `customer_register_success` event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you can define your observer as singleton for both events

```
<global>
    <events>
        <customer_save_after>
            <observers>
                <namespace_module>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>namespace_module/observer</class>
                    <method>doSomething</method>
                </namespace_module>
            </observers>
        </customer_save_after>
        <customer_register_success>
            <observers>
                <namespace_module>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>namespace_module/observer</class>
                    <method>doSomething</method>
                </namespace_module>
            </observers>
        </customer_register_success>
    </events>
</global>
```

In this case the same observer object will be used for both events. So you can create flag in your observer and before doing some actions check it.

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer
{
    protected $canDoSomething = false;

    public function doSomething($observer)
    {
        if (!$this->canDoSomething) {

            //here your code

            //now set flag to true to prevent executing your code twice 
            $this->canDoSomething = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now your code will be executed only once.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to prevent this is to use a registry value. Your observer method would look something like the following

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer
{
   public function triggeredObserver($observer)
   {
      if (!empty(Mage::registry('[module]_istriggered')) return $this;

      // here you can perform whatever you want to do with your code

      Mage::register('[module]_istriggered', 1);
   }
}
```

The first time the method is called it registeres a key, which means the second time it's triggered it's not empty anymore and the method will return at the start

Comment: Yeah I had thought about this, but it feels quite dirty :(.  I'm surprised that I cannot find out if an object has just been created in a model_save_after event

Comment: only a `before` event has the `isObjectNew` data as far as I know as the data is not saved yet. As far as dirty goes, I guess there would be more elegant ways but it's certainly not a hack

Comment: `$customer->save(); $this->_dispatchRegisterSuccess($customer);` unfortunately here, the customer is saved before the register event is triggered, so the observer method wouldn't work anyway :(

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to check which controller and action triggered the event.

In the observer you can get the module, controller and action name.

```
$frontName = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName();
$controllerName = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
$actionName = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName();

$myURI = $frontName . '_'. $controllerName . '_' . $actionName;
```

And later check in your method who's dispatching the event.

In a stock magento install, when creating a user from the user area the value of $myURI would be `customer_account_createpost`.